# Как создать автоклик на определенную кнопку на странице

Tags: javascript, html

Как создать автоклик на определенную кнопку к примеру "старт" на странице что бы при обновлении она не изменялась, а что как только этой кнопки "старт" не будет операция прекращалась, и как только она появиться операция начиналась снова

Comment: можно пример страницы?

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c850032/v850032906/aa0f/f-e_-56kE_o.jpg вот код страницы надо что бы кнопка Start Verification повторялось нажатие